# what causes the error in the jmh measurements?

Tags: java, jmh

I would like to know what could be the possible cause for having a margin of errors in the score results of jmh test. At the end of the day, it is the same code executed for a number of iterations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, taking a bait and assuming this is not an April 1 prank. You may start from here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observational_error
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_uncertainty

> "No measurement is exact. When a quantity is measured, the outcome
>   depends on the measuring system, the measurement procedure, the skill
>   of the operator, the environment, and other effects.[1] Even if the
>   quantity were to be measured several times, in the same way and in the
>   same circumstances, a different measured value would in general be
>   obtained each time, assuming the measuring system has sufficient
>   resolution to distinguish between the values."

Comment: So the systematic error can be reduced.One way of doing that would be choosing a large number of measurement iterations right ?

Comment: Both systematic and random errors cannot be reduced with more data. You can get a *better* *estimate* for sample mean and random error with more samples though.

Comment: I have a new question related to this one, I have two implementations of `compareAndSwap` and I have benchmarked both of them, one has higher score (op/ms) than the other, but also has an error that is a factor of 10^3 bigger. Should I neglect the error change ?